# How to create MultiUserChatRoom using XMPPFramework in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xmppframework

I am developing Chat Application using XMPPFramwwork in iPhone.I successfully completed one to one chat,now i want to develop multiuser chat in my application.

I tried the fallowing code but any delegate methods of XMPPRoomDelegate are not called.how can i start to create chat room.When and how the roomdelegate methods get called....any reply thanks inadvance.

```
XMPPStream *xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];

XMPPRoomCoreDataStorage *xmppRoomStorage  = [XMPPRoomCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];

XMPPJID *roomJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:@"vvreddy50@gmail.com"];

xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:xmppRoomStorage jid:roomJID dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

[xmppRoom   activate:xmppStream];
[xmppRoom   fetchConfigurationForm];
[xmppRoom   configureRoomUsingOptions:nil];
[xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[xmppRoom   addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

Comment: OP posted follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448784/how-to-create-a-multiuserchat-rooms-in-iphone-using-xmppframework

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. XMPPFramework is mostly asynchronous. That means you need to call `-fetchConfigurationForm` after you've authenticated, in your `-xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:` method.
   If those two calls need to be made in sequence, then call `-configureRoomUsingOptions` in `-xmppRoom:didFetchConfigurationForm:`.
2. Nothing at all will happen unless you call `-connect:` on the stream. Make sure to implement `-xmppStreamDidConnect:` and initiate authentication with the server in that method.

Comment: XMPPRoomDelegates are not called